# Has anyone written a plugin to add the final polish to ActiveResource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, activeresource

I have been using [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) in my Ruby on Rails applications for some time, and I am starting to really feel that it needs a final polish to make it go from "pretty nice" to "beautiful".

I would like to be able to use an ActiveResource as if it were an ActiveRecord.  If I could use `has\_many`, `belongs\_to` and other niceties with ActiveResources, it would make my life easier.

So I looked around for a plugin to do just that, but haven't had any luck finding one.  Has anyone written one? Does anyone know of an ongoing project?

---

#### **Raison d'être**

Let's say I have an application which manages `Users`, and another application which manages `UserRequests`.  I would like to avoid any circular dependency between my applications, therefore I have decided that the `Users` application will be completely unaware of the notion of `UserRequests`.  But of course, a `UserRequest` should belong to a `User`, and a `User` should have many `UserRequests`.

So, in the `Users` application, all I have is a `User` ActiveRecord, with all the necessary controller stuff to make it usable through ActiveResource.

The complicated stuff is in the `UserRequests` application.  I have a `UserRequest` ActiveRecord, and a `User` ActiveResource.  I would love to code the fact that a `UserRequest` `belongs_to` a User ActiveResource, and a `User` ActiveResource `has_many` `UserRequests`.

In another scenario where it could be the other way around (the ActiveRecord `has_many` ActiveResources, and the ActiveResource `belongs_to` the ActiveRecord).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran across the [Hyperactive Resource plugin](http://wiki.github.com/lukegalea/hyperactiveresource).  I am looking at it right now... looks good.

The funny thing is that I had decided to write my own plugin, and I was looking for a good name for it.  I wanted to find a name which would give the feeling that it was "ActiveResource++", an enhanced version of ActiveResource. I hesitated between "SexyResource" and "HyperactiveResource", and I decided that the former was not politically correct enough.  So I started to write my HyperactiveResource plugin... until I wondered if someone else had already thought of that name.  And it turns out someone did.  And the plugin was there.  Cool!  But it's kind of scary how we developers think alike, isn't it?  ;-)

Comment: I second this answer.  Disclaimer: I work with the guys who wrote HyperactiveResource.  It's good stuff and works well.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan Daigle [proposed](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/10/implement-ruby-proxy-objects-with-roxy) to do something similar with his Roxy gem. From his teaser section:

> I hope to have an extension library up
>   soon that utilizes Roxy to provide
>   ActiveRecord-like association
>   definitions in ActiveResource.

The example he gives shows how it wouldn't be too difficult to implement with [Roxy](http://github.com/yfactorial/roxy/tree/master).